# How can solve a scheduling problem a .ipnyb notebook in Sagemaker using AWS lambda and Lifecycle Configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jupyter-notebook

I want to schedule  my .ipynb file with Amazon Lambda. I am following the steps of this publications https://towardsdatascience.com/automating-aws-sagemaker-notebooks-2dec62bc2c84. For notebook instance is working very well starting and stoping, but my .ipynb file is not executing,  i wrote  as the same above mentioned publication in lifecycle configuration.

Just i change these lines with my notebook instance source
"NOTEBOOK_FILE="/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/Test Notebook.ipynb"
/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/activate "$ENVIRONMENT"
"source /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/deactivate".

Cloudwatch is working very well for notebook instance, but .ipynb file is not executed.

Can someone help me about my problem!

Comment: Can you provide the CloudWatch logs of the notebook instance and the lambda?

Comment: Yes I can, but just for notebook instace not for .ipynb file

Comment: Thats fine, please add them to your question

Comment: I have added Cloudwatch in question,if you know the answer please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the this aws-sample of how to run a notebook in aws-sagemaker.
This document shows how to install and run the sagemaker-run-notebooks library that lets you run and schedule Jupyter notebook executions as SageMaker Processing Jobs.
This library provides three interfaces to the notebook execution functionality:
A command line interface (CLI)
A Python library
A JupyterLab extension that can be enabled for JupyterLab running locally, in SageMaker Studio, or on a SageMaker notebook instance

https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-run-notebook

Also, check out this example of Scheduling Jupyter notebooks on SageMaker. you can write code in a Jupyter notebook and run it on an Amazon SageMaker ephemeral instance with the click of a button, either immediately or on a schedule. With the tools provided here, you can do this from anywhere: at a shell prompt, in JupyterLab on Amazon SageMaker, in another JupyterLab environment you have, or automated in a program you’ve written.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/scheduling-jupyter-notebooks-on-sagemaker-ephemeral-instances/

Comment: Thank you for reply, I will check , I hope one of them will solve my problem

Comment: I have not Found yet solution.  I try to do your answer description but I failed some where, please help me. Or some one who can help me to find the solution

Comment: @RefikNureddin did you found any solution for this?